# Do I have to pay the stamp duty additional charge when purchasing a house abroad?

Tags: united-kingdom, house, stamp-duty

I am in the process of purchasing a house in the UK. I own another house in Italy. I work and live in the UK.

Do I have to pay the stamp duty additional charge?

If I do so, do I qualify for stamp duty additional charge refund if I sell the property from Italy within three years?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which property is your main residence and whether there are other people who will live in the property with you.

There are plenty of good guides and SDLT calculators online that take you through it step by step, for example the Government guidance is [here](https://www.gov.uk/stamp-duty-land-tax/residential-property-rates) and [this site](https://www.moneyhelper.org.uk/en/homes/buying-a-home/everything-you-need-to-know-about-stamp-duty) has a calculator.